# API generated Bearer Token to login automatically over web GUI?

Tags: c#, wpf, api, .net-core, bearer-token

I'm developing a web application with C # and netcore, which includes an API module.
Then there is a windows WPF application (programmed by me) that can connect to this API.

So when I log in into my WPF application I check the credentials over the API's call and grant access to the user. In this WPF Application is a Button that will forward you to the Web version.
Is it now possible to hand over the generated bearer token from WPF App to my login in the web to grant the user access without using again his credentials?

I expect that the user just need to use his credentials in WPF App and is logged in in the browser too.

Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you store the token on the Web version and if you open it in the browser it will already be logged in and redirected to a specific page. In case the token cannot be retrieved or it is expired, then you will stay on the login page.

I would suggest you to pass the token to the login page as parameter in the URL from your WPF app. So at this point after you check if you already have a token stored, you can also check if you have any parameter passed, store that one and redirect to the page you want.

Comment: Ty i will try this :)